# Preferred Use of home_url()?

Tags: functions, customization, home-url

This isn't a problem but rather I am just curious to see how others are using this function. The codex does not really say a preferred method of use although it does provide some straight-forward examples.

For example if my domain is `example.com` I can write any of these:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/example">Example Page</a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>example">Example Page</a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/example') ); ?>">Example Page</a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('example') ); ?>">Example Page</a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('example', 'relative') ); ?>">Example Page</a>
```

And they will all output the same result (simplified) :

```
<a href="domain.com/example">Example Page</a>
```

I use the third example given most often and I understand the use of the last example, as at times I need to link to a secure page (https://), but what is the point of the other accepted variations?

Is one method considered a "best practice" or is it just left up to personal preference?

Comment: As a theme developer I've only ever used the first example which would link to the homepage, usually the logo or a banner. Any other links in the theme are either generated by the user or WordPress.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee when you say the links are generated by users or WordPress do you mean that they originate from the default content field? I end up using this when links are either needed to be hard coded or generated from an ACF input, and of course as you said for logos and banners

Comment: This is potentially off-topic because it's more opinion based, but I'd say the same as @Howdy_McGee - I've only ever used the first one. Other links either come from the menu system, from content fields, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Million ways in WordPress to use home_url() or sister functions. The question to ask is: What function is a wrapper for other function?

To summarize, if you like to concatenate you may use:

```
get_bloginfo('url');
get_option('home');
```

If you like to have the control over scheme (http or https)

```
get_site_url( $blog_id, $path, $scheme );
get_home_url( $blog_id, $path, $scheme );
site_url( $path, $scheme );
```

Where `site_url` calls `get_site_url`:

```
function site_url( $path = '', $scheme = null ) {
    return get_site_url( null, $path, $scheme );
}
```

You may like `get_bloginfo('url');` or `get_bloginfo('wpurl');`
since it will return:

```
    case 'url' :
        $output = home_url();
        break;
    case 'wpurl' :
        $output = site_url();
        break;
```

The primitive is: `get_option('home')`
Because function `get_home_url` calls `get_option('home')`.
What I wrote for `get_option('home')` is similar for `get_option('siteurl')` that came from `get_bloginfo('wpurl')`.

Comment: yea, I notice a lot of that with WordPress. I just don't think that it is necessary a lot of the time.